# Attach my app's icon to default Contacts app's Quick Action menu

Tags: android

The default Contacts app in Android has a very handy Quick Action menu when you tap on user's icon.

I would like to know whether anyone has been able to attach their own app to this menu and if so how they did it.

I would like to avoid writing my own contacts app just to provide a feature.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the QuickContactBadge. You can't force your app's icon in there. If you make your App able to send SMS, the user can then choose your App as the default to send SMS (as an example). If they check the box to make yours the default, You'll see your icon there next time they open a contact's quickBadge instead of the default Messaging icon.